# How to filter in Custom ListView with BaseAdapter

Tags: android, filtering, baseadapter

I can't seem to find how to make my custom `getFilter()` work.
My `CustomAdapter` extends `BaseAdapter` and as I have already understood it doesn't implements filtering so I need to do that by myself. I tried it in various ways but unsuccessfully.

Q1: What is the method working? (How do I implement filtering correctly?)

Q2: How do I change my `CustomAdapter`(!) so that filtering is an automatic feature?

Please, do not ignore!
Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's a piece of code:

**Main.java**

```
    //  import ....

    public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    ListView lv;
    Context context;
    EditText et;
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    View v;

    public  int [] Images=   {R.drawable.1,R.drawable.2,R.drawable.3,R.drawable.4};
    public  String [] NameList={"item1","item2","item3","item4"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context=this;

        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, fruitNameList,fruitImages);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs); // !!!!getFilter() is not found I tried to write methods on my own but nothing worked
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });



   }// end of onCreate

    public void onClick (View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.search:
                et.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                et.setHint("Search names...");

                break;
        }
    }

    public void SearchFilterEnable() {
        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
  //import...

  public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
  String [] result;
  Context context;
  int [] imageId;
  private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
  public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] NameList, int[] Images) {
    result=NameList;
    context=mainActivity;
    imageId=Images;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return result.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
   return position;
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView tv;
    ImageView img;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View v;
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.name_list, null);
    holder.tv=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.img=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    holder.tv.setText('\t'+result[position]);
    holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

         return v;
    }



}
```

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Could you post a *minimal* version of your code, just enough to reproduce the issue?

Comment: getFilter() doesn't call

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to change the underlying data of the adapter (aka filter the data) and then call `notifyDataSetChanged();` on the adapter. If you do so, your ListView will be informed that the dataset has been changed and will update its content.

You should store two Lists of your data in the adapter, one list with the original data and one list with the filtered data. The adapter itself operates on the filtered List and whenever you call your filter method, it just copies the data from your orginal list into the filtered list (based on your filter criteria).

```
private List<String> originalData;
private List<String> filteredData;

public void filter(String prefix) {
    filteredData = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String data : originalData) {
        if(data.startsWith(prefix)) filteredData.add(data);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: But how can I call getFilter() ?

Comment: I added some code to my answer. You don't have to call getFilter(), just implement a public filter(...) method and call it. And don't forget to call notifyDataSetChanged(); at the end of your custom filter method.

Comment: I'm sorry that I used List<String> in my example and not a String array. But it should be easy for you to convert the example to use String arrays. Or do you need more code?

Comment: to use string Arrays I've written  not List<String> but ArrayList<String>. Now trying to understand what to delete in my code and where to past your filter method (I'm only the very beginner)

Comment: That's ok ;)
I just tend to write something like:
`private List<String> filteredData = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: can I delete public void SearchFilterEnable(){…} ? Or I have to call filter(...) ; instead of the line MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

Comment: I would recommend to get rid of the Filterable interface. You do not really need it, because you extend BaseAdapter.
Then in your `onTextChanged()` just simply call
`MainActivity.this.adapter.filter(cs.toString());`

Comment: Thank you a lot for help!!! But now I'm faced with prob that program crashes when I try to type smth.(

Comment: could you please post a stacktrace?

Comment: While debugging it goes to MainActivity.this.adapter.filter(cs.toString()); after stands on for(String data:originalData)  in my adapter method filter(); and opens ZygoteInit.java and give me to read static native int getpgid(int pid) throws IOException;

Comment: Did you populate the originalData List with the `String[] NameList` parameter from you adapter constructor?
If not, please add `originalData = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(NameList));` to your constructor.

Comment: Furthermore, you should always start parameter names with a lowercase letter. So `String[] NameList` should be `String[] nameList! Java conventions... ;)

Comment: My fool( I haven't initialised correctly what is originalData. Now doesn't crash and doesn't search...

Comment: Will say it in another way, it sorts but I can't see only filtered items on my screen.

Comment: Kira, can you please explain a little bit more in detail, what you want to achieve? I see a TextField with a listener, and on each keypress you wanna filter the whole list of names based on the substring you entered in this textfield, right? 
Your CustomAdapter must always work with the filteredData List, so each method that you have overriden from BaseAdapter must use filteredData. For example the `getItem()`method must look like this:

`@Override

public Object getItem(int position) {

    return filteredList.get(position);

}`

Comment: Exactly rigth)))On each keypress I'd like to see only that names which starts on my prefix. You're a great answerer! Thank you so much for your hand of help and patience to answer on my stupid questions, which appear step by step when I'm changing smth:) I actually tried to change all the @Override with my adapter methods in that way you told me but it crashed when starting)))) It seems to me I'm unready to solve filtering on my own yet. Have to study before. Thanks anyway!!!